# get web page data through class name

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I need to get the dates and temp from a weather website and record it on  cells but I am getting a `object variable or with block variable not set` error.

I tried to data from web in excel but I think the website is protected or something because I keep getting "under maintenance" page when trying to load the page from excel. I got the codes below from a tutorial but I can't make it work.

```
Sub record()

    Dim request As Object
    Dim response As String
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim websie As String
    Dim temps As Variant

    'provide link
    'website = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EURUSD=X?p=EURUSD=X"
    website = "https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/chicago/60608/september-weather/348308"

    'create the object that will make the webpage request
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    'go to the link
    request.Open "GET", website, False

    'send request for webpage
    request.send

    'get web response data to variable
    response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

    'put webpage to an html object
    html.body.innerHTML = response

    'get temperature from specified element
    'temps = html.getElementsByClassName("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")(0).innerText
    temps = html.getElementsByClassName("high")(0).innerText


     Sheets("record").Range("A1") = temps

End Sub
```

Sample lines from the website:

```
<a class="monthly-daypanel is-past">
   <div class="date">2</div>
   <div class="icon-container"...</div>
   <div class="temp">
      <div class="high">83</div>
      <div class="low">83</div>
   </div>
</a>
```

I want to get the `date`, `high` and `low`.

Comment: Which line is highlighted when error appears?

Comment: this one `temps = html.getElementsByClassName("high")(0).innerText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an User-Agent header. I would also extract the json string from one of the script tags (I use regex for this) and use that as source. I add in a date comparison to work out if it is a forecast or actual value. I read the json string into json object using json library and loop the resultant collection storing items of interest in an array for faster writing out to sheet at end.

**json library:**

I use jsonconverter.bas. Download raw code from [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) and add to standard module called jsonConverter . You then need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetWeatherListings()

    Dim s As String, re As Object, ws As Worksheet

    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/chicago/60608/september-weather/348308", False
       ' .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        s = .responsetext
    End With

    Dim results(), r As Long, jsonSource As String, json As Object, item As Object

    jsonSource = GetString(re, s, "dailyForecast = (.*?\])")

    If jsonSource = "No match" Then Exit Sub

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonSource)

    ReDim results(1 To json.count, 1 To 4) 'date, datetime,  day > dActual, night > dActual

    Dim dateTime() As String, datePart As String, forecast As Boolean

    For Each item In json
        r = r + 1
        dateTime = Split(item("dateTime"), "T")
        datePart = dateTime(LBound(dateTime))
        forecast = CDate(datePart) >= Date
        results(r, 1) = datePart
        results(r, 2) = item("dateTime")
        results(r, 3) = IIf(forecast, item("day")("dTemp"), item("day")("dActual"))
        results(r, 4) = IIf(forecast, item("night")("dTemp"), item("night")("dActual"))
    Next

    Dim headers()

    headers = Array("Date", "DateTime", "Day temp", "Night temp")

    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal re As Object, ByVal inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    Dim matches As Object

    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = pattern
        If .Test(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
            GetString = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With
    GetString = "No match"
End Function
```

---

**Sample of end of output:**

[image]

Comment: I already referenced `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` but im still getting `variable not defined` on this line `Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonSource)`.

Comment: Did you add the code from the link to a standard module named JsonConverter?

Comment: Also, remove the top line from the code you copy across _Attribute VB_Name = "JsonConverter"_

Comment: Its working now but it errors out on the third loop `subscript out of range` on this part `results(r, 1) = datePart`

Comment: I just ran it twice without a problem. If it happens again you need to inspect the value of  json.count. I do notice that currently @ 06:05 GMT yesterday's date has only Hist Avg on the web page and thus code currently therefore returns nothing for that date.

Comment: Did you tried to run it on a loop with different dates?

Comment: Nope as the question didn't ask for that. The code gets all the dates and temps as currently listed for your given url. That page appears to update. Unless you mean a loop of all dates on that page - in which case, yes

Comment: Sorry I mean different links

Comment: :-) Nope. Question didn't ask for that. I have no idea what those other links would be. You could open a new question and I would be happy to have a look but please include the new links and be sure to indicate where the code is falling over and what you suspect is the problem.

Comment: Ill post another question. The links would be from the same site but just different places (ie. Chicago, Denver, etc. Thanks

Comment: No worries. Drop me a link to the new question and I will have a look and see if we can work out what is going on.